# When using Google Closure Builder, can I use my existing deps.js file instead of tracing paths?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, closures, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I am trying to reduce my build time while using closureBuilder. I am also using the closureDepsWriter tool to generate a deps.js file, and this task is very quick. I can see that closureBuilder traces ~1500 sources, even though I only have a few hundred in my source directory. So, considering that closureDepsWriter is able to quickly generate a dependency tree , is it possible to use this tree as input into closureBuilder? I would like to avoid writing a custom concatenation tool that reads from deps.js.

I have looked through the closureBuilder documentation to see if there are any command line options that would allow this, but I am coming up blank.

Answer (score 1):

All of the python scripts you mentioned (depswriter, closurebuilder) are no longer the best way to compile scripts. Instead, utilize the ability to pass globs to closure-compiler and use the `--manage-closure-dependencies` related flags. See https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Manage-Closure-Dependencies

Example:

```
java -jar compiler.jar -O=ADVANCED -W=VEBOSE --only_closure_dependencies
  --closure_entry_point=foo.bar --js='closure-library/**.js' --js='mycoderoot/**.js'
```

Comment: If i switch your answer to -O=WHITESPACE_ONLY it is about twice as fast as closurebuilder, but still takes 5+ seconds, which is considerably slower than depsWriter.py + a simple concat. Unfortunately, what I really need here is speed for concating all the files in dependency order, the slower compilation tasks can be run later.